# ASP.NET Read Resources values

Tags: asp.net, multilingual, resourcemanager

I have two `.resx` files: `en.resx` and `he.resx`, in the folder `App_LocalResources`.
I already have two buttons in my web page, clicking each one is supposed to "switch" to the other language's resource file.

I want to simply get a string value located in one of the `.resx` files.

I tried some of the examples I have found on google, and I asked myself, why do I need to provide an `Assembly` type and a namespace, when i just want to ask for a `string` value in my own project?

Why isn't there something like: `string val = Resources["en.resx"]["SomeProperty"].Value`?

Maybe my whole approach is wrong, and I would like to read your opinions.

Thanks, Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Resources;

ResXResourceSet Resource = new ResXResourceSet(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Properties/Resource.resx")
String value=Resource.GetStrin("key");
```

Comment: include system.windows.forms; 
also to you refernece